# Outlook MAPI Message Class Metadata in Outlook 2016

Tags: powershell, outlook

I've been looking all over and I can't seem to find anywhere that MS has this information documented.  (This includes the [MS documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc839595.aspx) on MAPI message classes.  This [Super User answer](https://superuser.com/questions/555304/how-to-search-for-item-type-in-outlook/713419) elucidates what seems to be all of the standard Message Classes that are possible, but I haven't been able to find a list of the possible metadata that are associated with the Message Classes.

Does anyone know where I can find the metadata for each of the Message Classes as well as a possible brief (or detailed!) description of what the column means? Some of them are pretty obvious ("ReceivedDate", Start, etc.) but others are less obvious.

I've munged around with PowerShell and managed to find the following:

Schedule Meeting Request:

```
        "Application",
        "Class",
        "Session",
        "Parent",
        "Actions",
        "Attachments",
        "BillingInformation",
        "Body",
        "Categories",
        "Companies ",
        "ConversationIndex",
        "ConversationTopic",
        "CreationTime",
        "EntryID",
        "FormDescription",
        "GetInspector",
        "Importance",
        "LastModificationTime",
        "MAPIOBJECT",
        "MessageClass",
        "Mileage",
        "NoAging",
        "OutlookInternalVersion",
        "OutlookVersion",
        "Saved",
        "Sensitivity",
        "Size",
        "Subject",
        "UnRead",
        "UserProperties",
        "AutoForwarded",
        "DeferredDeliveryTime",
        "DeleteAfterSubmit",
        "ExpiryTime",
        "FlagDueBy",
        "FlagRequest ",
        "FlagStatus",
        "OriginatorDeliveryReportRequested",
        "ReceivedTime",
        "Recipients",
        "ReminderSet",
        "ReminderTime",
        "ReplyRecipients",
        "SaveSentMessageFolder",
        "SenderName",
        "Sent",
        "SentOn",
        "Submitted",
        "Links",
        "DownloadState",
        "ItemProperties",
        "MarkForDownload",
        "IsConflict",
        "MeetingWorkspaceURL",
        "FlagIcon",
        "AutoResolvedWinner",
        "Conflicts",
        "SenderEmailAddress",
        "SenderEmailType",
        "PropertyAccessor",
        "ConversationID",
        "SendUsingAccount",
        "IsLatestVersion",
        "RTFBody",
        "RetentionExpirationDate",
        "RetentionPolicyName",
        "BodyFormat"
```

RSS:

```
"Application",
        "Class",
        "Session",
        "Parent",
        "Actions",
        "Attachments",
        "BillingInformation",
        "Body",
        "Categories",
        "Companies",
        "ConversationIndex",
        "ConversationTopic",
        "CreationTime",
        "EntryID",
        "FormDescription",
        "GetInspector",
        "Importance",
        "LastModificationTime",
        "MAPIOBJECT",
        "MessageClass",
        "Mileage",
        "NoAging",
        "OutlookInternalVersion",
        "OutlookVersion",
        "Saved",
        "Sensitivity",
        "Size",
        "Subject",
        "UnRead",
        "UserProperties",
        "ExpiryTime",
        "HTMLBody",
        "ReceivedTime",
        "SenderName",
        "SentOn",
        "Links",
        "ItemProperties",
        "BodyFormat",
        "DownloadState",
        "InternetCodepage",
        "MarkForDownload",
        "IsConflict",
        "AutoResolvedWinner",
        "Conflicts",
        "SenderEmailAddress",
        "SenderEmailType",
        "PropertyAccessor",
        "TaskSubject",
        "TaskDueDate",
        "TaskStartDate",
        "TaskCompletedDate",
        "ToDoTaskOrdinal",
        "ReminderOverrideDefault",
        "ReminderPlaySound",
        "ReminderSet",
        "ReminderSoundFile",
        "ReminderTime",
        "IsMarkedAsTask",
        "ConversationID",
        "RTFBody"
```

Notes:

```
"Application",
        "Class",
        "Session",
        "Parent",
        "Body",
        "Categories",
        "Color",
        "CreationTime",
        "EntryID",
        "GetInspector",
        "Height",
        "LastModificationTime",
        "Left",
        "MessageClass",
        "Saved",
        "Size",
        "Subject",
        "Top",
        "Width",
        "Links",
        "DownloadState",
        "ItemProperties",
        "MarkForDownload",
        "IsConflict",
        "AutoResolvedWinner",
        "Conflicts",
        "PropertyAccessor"
```

Contact:

```
"Application",
        "Class",
        "Session",
        "Parent",
        "Actions",
        "Attachments",
        "BillingInformation",
        "Body",
        "Categories",
        "Companies",
        "ConversationIndex",
        "ConversationTopic",
        "CreationTime",
        "EntryID",
        "FormDescription",
        "GetInspector",
        "Importance",
        "LastModificationTime",
        "MAPIOBJECT",
        "MessageClass",
        "Mileage",
        "NoAging",
        "OutlookInternalVersion",
        "OutlookVersion",
        "Saved",
        "Sensitivity",
        "Size",
        "Subject",
        "UnRead",
        "UserProperties",
        "Account",
        "Anniversary",
        "AssistantName",
        "AssistantTelephoneNumber",
        "Birthday",
        "Business2TelephoneNumber",
        "BusinessAddress",
        "BusinessAddressCity",
        "BusinessAddressCountry",
        "BusinessAddressPostalCode",
        "BusinessAddressPostOfficeBox",
        "BusinessAddressState",
        "BusinessAddressStreet",
        "BusinessFaxNumber",
        "BusinessHomePage",
        "BusinessTelephoneNumber",
        "CallbackTelephoneNumber",
        "CarTelephoneNumber",
        "Children",
        "CompanyAndFullName",
        "CompanyLastFirstNoSpace",
        "CompanyLastFirstSpaceOnly",
        "CompanyMainTelephoneNumber",
        "CompanyName",
        "ComputerNetworkName",
        "CustomerID",
        "Department",
        "Email1Address",
        "Email1AddressType",
        "Email1DisplayName",
        "Email1EntryID",
        "Email2Address",
        "Email2AddressType",
        "Email2DisplayName",
        "Email2EntryID",
        "Email3Address",
        "Email3AddressType",
        "Email3DisplayName",
        "Email3EntryID",
        "FileAs",
        "FirstName",
        "FTPSite",
        "FullName",
        "FullNameAndCompany",
        "Gender",
        "GovernmentIDNumber",
        "Hobby",
        "Home2TelephoneNumber",
        "HomeAddress",
        "HomeAddressCity",
        "HomeAddressCountry",
        "HomeAddressPostalCode",
        "HomeAddressPostOfficeBox",
        "HomeAddressState",
        "HomeAddressStreet",
        "HomeFaxNumber",
        "HomeTelephoneNumber",
        "Initials",
        "InternetFreeBusyAddress",
        "ISDNNumber",
        "JobTitle",
        "Journal",
        "Language",
        "LastFirstAndSuffix",
        "LastFirstNoSpace",
        "LastFirstNoSpaceCompany",
        "LastFirstSpaceOnly",
        "LastFirstSpaceOnlyCompany",
        "LastName",
        "LastNameAndFirstName",
        "MailingAddress",
        "MailingAddressCity",
        "MailingAddressCountry",
        "MailingAddressPostalCode",
        "MailingAddressPostOfficeBox",
        "MailingAddressState",
        "MailingAddressStreet",
        "ManagerName",
        "MiddleName",
        "MobileTelephoneNumber",
        "NetMeetingAlias",
        "NetMeetingServer",
        "NickName",
        "OfficeLocation",
        "OrganizationalIDNumber",
        "OtherAddress",
        "OtherAddressCity",
        "OtherAddressCountry",
        "OtherAddressPostalCode",
        "OtherAddressPostOfficeBox",
        "OtherAddressState",
        "OtherAddressStreet",
        "OtherFaxNumber",
        "OtherTelephoneNumber",
        "PagerNumber",
        "PersonalHomePage",
        "PrimaryTelephoneNumber",
        "Profession",
        "RadioTelephoneNumber",
        "ReferredBy",
        "SelectedMailingAddress",
        "Spouse",
        "Suffix",
        "TelexNumber",
        "Title",
        "TTYTDDTelephoneNumber",
        "User1",
        "User2",
        "User3",
        "User4",
        "UserCertificate",
        "WebPage",
        "YomiCompanyName",
        "YomiFirstName",
        "YomiLastName",
        "Links",
        "ItemProperties",
        "LastFirstNoSpaceAndSuffix",
        "DownloadState",
        "IMAddress",
        "MarkForDownload",
        "IsConflict",
        "AutoResolvedWinner",
        "Conflicts",
        "HasPicture",
        "PropertyAccessor",
        "TaskSubject",
        "TaskDueDate",
        "TaskStartDate",
        "TaskCompletedDate",
        "ToDoTaskOrdinal",
        "ReminderOverrideDefault",
        "ReminderPlaySound",
        "ReminderSet",
        "ReminderSoundFile",
        "ReminderTime",
        "IsMarkedAsTask",
        "BusinessCardLayoutXml",
        "BusinessCardType",
        "ConversationID",
        "RTFBody"
```

Conversations:

```
"Application",
        "Class",
        "Session",
        "Parent",
        "Actions",
        "Attachments",
        "BillingInformation",
        "Body",
        "Categories",
        "Companies",
        "ConversationIndex",
        "ConversationTopic",
        "CreationTime",
        "EntryID",
        "FormDescription",
        "GetInspector",
        "Importance",
        "LastModificationTime",
        "MAPIOBJECT",
        "MessageClass",
        "Mileage",
        "NoAging",
        "OutlookInternalVersion",
        "OutlookVersion",
        "Saved",
        "Sensitivity",
        "Size",
        "Subject",
        "UnRead",
        "UserProperties",
        "AlternateRecipientAllowed",
        "AutoForwarded",
        "BCC",
        "CC",
        "DeferredDeliveryTime",
        "DeleteAfterSubmit",
        "ExpiryTime",
        "FlagDueBy",
        "FlagRequest",
        "FlagStatus",
        "HTMLBody",
        "OriginatorDeliveryReportRequested",
        "ReadReceiptRequested",
        "ReceivedByEntryID",
        "ReceivedByName",
        "ReceivedOnBehalfOfEntryID",
        "ReceivedOnBehalfOfName",
        "ReceivedTime",
        "RecipientReassignmentProhibited",
        "Recipients",
        "ReminderOverrideDefault",
        "ReminderPlaySound",
        "ReminderSet",
        "ReminderSoundFile",
        "ReminderTime",
        "RemoteStatus",
        "ReplyRecipientNames",
        "ReplyRecipients",
        "SaveSentMessageFolder",
        "SenderName",
        "Sent",
        "SentOn",
        "SentOnBehalfOfName",
        "Submitted",
        "[To]",
        "VotingOptions",
        "VotingResponse",
        "Links",
        "ItemProperties",
        "BodyFormat",
        "DownloadState",
        "InternetCodepage",
        "MarkForDownload",
        "IsConflict",
        "IsIPFax",
        "FlagIcon",
        "HasCoverSheet",
        "AutoResolvedWinner",
        "Conflicts",
        "SenderEmailAddress",
        "SenderEmailType",
        "EnableSharedAttachments",
        "Permission",
        "PermissionService",
        "PropertyAccessor",
        "SendUsingAccount",
        "TaskSubject",
        "TaskDueDate",
        "TaskStartDate",
        "TaskCompletedDate",
        "ToDoTaskOrdinal",
        "IsMarkedAsTask",
        "ConversationID",
        "Sender",
        "PermissionTemplateGuid",
        "RTFBody",
        "RetentionPolicyName",
        "RetentionExpirationDate"
```

Tasks:

```
"Application",
        "Class",
        "Session",
        "Parent",
        "Actions",
        "Attachments",
        "BillingInformation",
        "Body",
        "Categories",
        "Companies",
        "ConversationIndex",
        "ConversationTopic",
        "CreationTime",
        "EntryID",
        "FormDescription",
        "GetInspector",
        "Importance",
        "LastModificationTime",
        "MAPIOBJECT",
        "MessageClass",
        "Mileage",
        "NoAging",
        "OutlookInternalVersion",
        "OutlookVersion",
        "Saved",
        "Sensitivity",
        "Size",
        "Subject",
        "UnRead",
        "UserProperties",
        "ActualWork",
        "CardData",
        "Complete",
        "Contacts",
        "ContactNames",
        "DateCompleted",
        "DelegationState",
        "Delegator",
        "DueDate",
        "IsRecurring",
        "Ordinal",
        "Owner",
        "Ownership",
        "PercentComplete",
        "Recipients",
        "ReminderTime",
        "ReminderOverrideDefault",
        "ReminderPlaySound",
        "ReminderSet",
        "ReminderSoundFile",
        "ResponseState",
        "Role",
        "SchedulePlusPriority",
        "StartDate",
        "Status",
        "StatusOnCompletionRecipients",
        "StatusUpdateRecipients",
        "TeamTask",
        "TotalWork",
        "Links",
        "DownloadState",
        "ItemProperties",
        "InternetCodepage",
        "MarkForDownload",
        "IsConflict",
        "AutoResolvedWinner",
        "Conflicts",
        "PropertyAccessor",
        "SendUsingAccount",
        "ToDoTaskOrdinal",
        "ConversationID",
        "RTFBody",
```

Calendar:

```
"Application",
        "Class",
        "Session",
        "Parent",
        "Actions",
        "Attachments",
        "BillingInformation",
        "Body",
        "Categories",
        "Companies",
        "ConversationIndex",
        "ConversationTopic",
        "CreationTime",
        "EntryID",
        "FormDescription",
        "GetInspector",
        "Importance",
        "LastModificationTime",
        "MAPIOBJECT",
        "MessageClass",
        "Mileage",
        "NoAging",
        "OutlookInternalVersion",
        "OutlookVersion",
        "Saved",
        "Sensitivity",
        "Size",
        "Subject",
        "UnRead",
        "UserProperties",
        "AllDayEvent",
        "BusyStatus",
        "Duration",
        "End",
        "IsOnlineMeeting",
        "IsRecurring",
        "Location",
        "MeetingStatus",
        "NetMeetingAutoStart",
        "NetMeetingOrganizerAlias",
        "NetMeetingServer",
        "NetMeetingType",
        "OptionalAttendees",
        "Organizer",
        "Recipients",
        "RecurrenceState",
        "ReminderMinutesBeforeStart",
        "ReminderOverrideDefault",
        "ReminderPlaySound",
        "ReminderSet",
        "ReminderSoundFile",
        "ReplyTime",
        "RequiredAttendees",
        "Resources",
        "ResponseRequested",
        "ResponseStatus",
        "Start",
        "NetMeetingDocPathName",
        "NetShowURL",
        "Links",
        "ConferenceServerAllowExternal",
        "ConferenceServerPassword",
        "ItemProperties",
        "DownloadState",
        "InternetCodepage",
        "MarkForDownload",
        "IsConflict",
        "MeetingWorkspaceURL",
        "AutoResolvedWinner",
        "Conflicts",
        "PropertyAccessor",
        "SendUsingAccount",
        "GlobalAppointmentID",
        "ForceUpdateToAllAttendees",
        "StartUTC",
        "EndUTC",
        "StartInStartTimeZone",
        "EndInEndTimeZone",
        "StartTimeZone",
        "EndTimeZone",
        "ConversationID",
        "RTFBody",
        "BodyFormat"
```

e-mail (IPM.Note):

```
"Application",
        "Class",
        "Session",
        "Parent",
        "Actions",
        "Attachments",
        "BillingInformation",
        "Body",
        "Categories",
        "Companies",
        "ConversationIndex",
        "ConversationTopic",
        "CreationTime",
        "EntryID",
        "FormDescription",
        "GetInspector",
        "Importance",
        "LastModificationTime",
        "MAPIOBJECT",
        "MessageClass",
        "Mileage",
        "NoAging",
        "OutlookInternalVersion",
        "OutlookVersion",
        "Saved",
        "Sensitivity",
        "Size",
        "Subject",
        "UnRead",
        "UserProperties",
        "AlternateRecipientAllowed",
        "AutoForwarded",
        "BCC",
        "CC",
        "DeferredDeliveryTime",
        "DeleteAfterSubmit",
        "ExpiryTime",
        "FlagDueBy",
        "FlagRequest",
        "FlagStatus",
        "HTMLBody",
        "OriginatorDeliveryReportRequested",
        "ReadReceiptRequested",
        "ReceivedByEntryID",
        "ReceivedByName",
        "ReceivedOnBehalfOfEntryID",
        "ReceivedOnBehalfOfName",
        "ReceivedTime",
        "RecipientReassignmentProhibited",
        "Recipients",
        "ReminderOverrideDefault",
        "ReminderPlaySound",
        "ReminderSet",
        "ReminderSoundFile",
        "ReminderTime",
        "RemoteStatus",
        "ReplyRecipientNames",
        "ReplyRecipients",
        "SaveSentMessageFolder",
        "SenderName",
        "Sent",
        "SentOn",
        "SentOnBehalfOfName",
        "Submitted",
        "[To]",
        "VotingOptions",
        "VotingResponse",
        "Links",
        "ItemProperties",
        "BodyFormat",
        "DownloadState",
        "InternetCodepage",
        "MarkForDownload",
        "IsConflict",
        "IsIPFax",
        "FlagIcon",
        "HasCoverSheet",
        "AutoResolvedWinner",
        "Conflicts",
        "SenderEmailAddress",
        "SenderEmailType",
        "EnableSharedAttachments",
        "Permission",
        "PermissionService",
        "PropertyAccessor",
        "SendUsingAccount",
        "TaskSubject",
        "TaskDueDate",
        "TaskStartDate",
        "TaskCompletedDate",
        "ToDoTaskOrdinal",
        "IsMarkedAsTask",
        "ConversationID",
        "Sender",
        "PermissionTemplateGuid",
        "RTFBody",
        "RetentionPolicyName",
        "RetentionExpirationDate"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Microsoft Outlook object browser displays the classes, properties, methods, and events available from the Outlook object library.

If you do not see the Developer tab, see [Run in Developer Mode in Outlook](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/run-in-developer-mode-in-outlook) to activate the Developer tab. On the Developer tab, in the Form group, click View Code to open the Script Editor. In the Script Editor, click Object Browser on the Script menu or press F2.

All of the available Outlook objects are listed in the Classes pane of the object browser in alphabetical order. To view the members of an object, select the object in the Classes pane. The members of this object appear in alphabetical order in the Members of pane. The heading at the top of this pane will reflect the name of the object that you select. For example, if you select the `AppointmentItem` object in the Classes pane, the heading of the Members of pane will appear as Members of `AppointmentItem`.

The interfaces and members of the `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook` namespace that provide support for interoperability between the COM object model of Outlook and managed applications that automate Outlook are described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn320433.aspx).